# Adding a gerrit group as reviewer

Tags: gerrit, git-review

I have gerrit group named "UI_Developers"

I am using the following command to submit my changes for review:

```
git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master%r=abc@morg.com
```

But, I want to add all the members in the UI_Developers group as reviewers command line. Using UI this is easy, by using command line, any idea how to add an entire gerrit group as reviewer?

PS:`ssh -p  ...set-reviewers -a reviewer`
method is quite cumbersome hence I am not looking for it.

Comment: Did you look if the git config as described on https://code.google.com/p/gerrit/source/browse/Documentation/cmd-receive-pack.txt might be an acceptable way for you?

Comment: i think it is not supported yet - group name can not be add as a reviewer

Comment: Update: Seven years later and this important feature is still not supported...

Answer (score 9):

Adding groups as reviewers when pushing doesn't seem to be supported by Gerrit yet.

This is a related [feature request](https://code.google.com/p/gerrit/issues/detail?id=1853) which is open as of August 2016:

> Currently, the --reviewer only takes account identifier (email) as
>   parameter. It could be updated to take a group name as argument.
>
> My use case is that we have groups corresponding to our development
>   teams. Developers often want to add their whole team as reviewer for
>   their changes. Currently they need either to add --reviewer manually
>   to their receivepack command (and keep in sync with team changes) or
>   go to the web interface to add the whole group at once. Having the
>   ability to add the group directly from the receivepack would ease the
>   process.